# "sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked" error when generating MBTiles in QGIS

Tags: raster, qgis-3, mbtiles, xyz-tiles

On Windows 10 Enterprise 20H2 (Build 19042.1706) with QGIS 3.22.5-Białowieża I am getting the following error together with the log:

```
QGIS version: 3.22.5-Białowieża
QGIS code revision: c2723178
Qt version: 5.15.2
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.4.1
GEOS version: 3.10.2-CAPI-1.16.0
PROJ version: Rel. 8.2.1, January 1st, 2022
PDAL version: 2.3.0 (git-version: 9f35b7)
Algorithm started at: 2022-05-19T10:34:34
Algorithm 'Generate XYZ tiles (MBTiles)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BACKGROUND_COLOR' : QColor(0, 0, 0, 0), 'DPI' : 96, 'EXTENT' : '511960.000000000,514565.000000000,5397510.000000000,5399560.000000000 [EPSG:25832]', 'METATILESIZE' : 4, 'OUTPUT_FILE' : 'R:/.../offline_basemap_lhs_stadtkarte.mbtiles', 'QUALITY' : 90, 'TILE_FORMAT' : 0, 'ZOOM_MAX' : 20, 'ZOOM_MIN' : 16 }

Using 6 CPU Threads:
Generating tiles for zoom level: 16
Generating tiles for zoom level: 17
Generating tiles for zoom level: 18
Generating tiles for zoom level: 19
Generating tiles for zoom level: 20
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 455, in processAlgorithm
self.generate(writer, parameters, context, feedback)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 316, in generate
for result in threadPool.map(self.renderSingleMetatile, metatiles_by_zoom[zoom]):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.5\apps\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 608, in result_iterator
yield fs.pop().result()
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.5\apps\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 445, in result
return self.__get_result()
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.5\apps\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
raise self._exception
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.5\apps\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run
result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 230, in renderSingleMetatile
self.writer.write_tile(tile, tileImage)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 401, in write_tile
self._init_zoom_layer(tile.z)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 393, in _init_zoom_layer
self._execute_sqlite("UPDATE metadata SET value='{}' WHERE name='bounds'".format(bounds))
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 373, in _execute_sqlite
conn.execute(cmd)
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Execution failed after 72.20 seconds (1 minute 12 seconds)

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Generate XYZ tiles (MBTiles)' finished
```

It had happened after applying the ["Generate XYZ tiles (MBTiles)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rastertools.html#generate-xyz-tiles-mbtiles) geoalgorithm. I could get the output even with this error.

With this tool I tried to create an offline tiled map, here are the settings:

[image: settings]

What could go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens when one tries to override already existing *.mbtiles* file.

A working solution is either (1) delete the existing output and write a new file or (2) write the output to a new file with a different name.

And also as was mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47738#issuecomment-1099697477):

> The workaround I found was using QGIS 3.20.3

For more details see also : [GenerateXYZ (MBTiles) multithreading problem #47738](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47738)